# Django using arguments in form action with CSRF token

Tags: django, forms, variables, csrf, args

I'm trying to create a Form for updating a Contact elemnt. The form action I want to link back to a URL, but the URL is based on the contact_id. When I try to add a contact_id variable into the form action, my CSRF token is escaping it so it doesn't read it as a variable. Is there a way to bypass this or am I approaching this the wrong way?

**views.py**

```
def contactedit(request, contact_id=1):
    if request.POST:
        contact = Contact.objects.get(id=contact_id)
        form = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=contact)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/{{ contact_id }}/')

    else:
        contact = Contact.objects.get(id=contact_id)
        form = ContactForm(instance=contact)

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form
    args['contact_id'] = contact_id

    return render_to_response('contactedit.html', args)
```

**contactedit.html**

`<form action="/contact/{{ contact_id }}/edit/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}`

**Error**
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    (ipaddress)/contact/%7B%7B%20contact_id%20%7D%7D/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is failing at

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/{{ contact_id }}/')
```

You are trying to use template syntax here, rather you should do

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/'+str(contact_id))
```

---

Apart from that your code will not handle case when form is not valid and will call same code. You may want to show the form again with errors when form is not valid. Refer form handling docs from django.

Comment: I guess I totally misinterpreted where the error was. Your suggestion fixed it. Thanks a lot. The form errors is the next thing that I was going to work on.